# QT Process gets killed automatically when it hits in SLOT

Tags: qt

I have written a QT code which starts a new process on a button click, that process have to execute a shell script and append the Std output/error on text Browser dynamically based upon the script result. The code gets failed in the custom Slot. This is what my **window.h** is

```
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QPushButton *goButton;
    QTextBrowser *statusWindow;
    QProcess *process;

private slots:
    void go_Button_Clicked();
    void updateOutput();
};
```

And this is how my **window.cpp** is

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
 // Text Browser 
    statusWindow = new QTextBrowser(this);
 // Create the Go button, make "this" the parent
    goButton = new QPushButton(this);
    connect(goButton, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (go_Button_Clicked()));
}
void Window::go_Button_Clicked()
{
    // Step1 - Create a new process
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    // Step2 - Connect the Signals and slot
    qDebug() << connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(updateOutput()));
    // Step3 - Start the Script process
    process->start("/home/root/script.sh");
    qDebug() << "Process in main";

}
void Window::updateOutput()
{
    qDebug() << "Process in update Output";
    //statusWindow->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

So whenever i uncommented lines in update Output the GUI crashes as soon as i hit the button. using qdebug i managed to find that the GUI crashes bcoz of the line "statusWindow->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());" .

If the line is commented the debug message keeps on printing on console, but with the un-commented line i get the debug message once and then GUI crashes.Here is the debug output.

```
true 
true 
Process in main 
Process in update Output 
Process killed by signal
```

Any idea whats going on here, and i am familiar with Debugging in QT

Comment: @G.M that was a mistake i missed to add the code here, it's along with the Go button. You can check the updated post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
```

by

```
process = new QProcess(this);
```

You are using uninitialized member variable process, because in `Window::go_Button_Clicked()` you are creating a local variable.

**Edit**

Actually, the code is very error prone. What happens, when the user presses the button multiple times. Then in the slot you may read the the output from wrong process.
One workaround could be: You don't define QProcess as member at all, but do it like now - as a local variable. Then in the slot, you can cast the sender to QProcess*, and unless it fails use this instance. It will be always the right one. Afterwards, don't forget to delete the sender. Use deleteLater() for this.

Comment: When he hit button second time he'll get memory leak.

Comment: @Evgeny the suggestion to improve was on the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `void Window::go_Button_Clicked()` slote you hide `QProcess *process` declared at `.h` file with new variable

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
```

Replace this line with

```
process = new QProcess(this);
```

But when you click second time you'll get memory leak, and can not get more data from first process. So you chould change you design somehow.